# How to reinstall Windows Service using installutil after making changes in code

Tags: vb.net, windows-services, installutil

I wrote a test Windows service and installed it using installutil which went fine.

After that I made changes in my code and tried to install again but got error. 
Do I need to remove the service first, then install again using installutil? Or is there other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the name of executable is the same then you can simply stop the Windows service, copy new files on top of the old ones and start the service.

Comment: My problem is that the windows service won't stop properly, it keeps getting an error message: The service cannot accept control messages at this time.